# как можно в javascript выделить все input и required поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить все обязательные инпуты в javascript?

.getElementsByTagName("input");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Суть где-то тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
const requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[required]')

requiredInputs.forEach(i => console.log(i.id))
```

```html
<input id="i1" required/>
<input id="i2" />
<input id="i3" />
<input id="i4" />
<input id="i5" />
<input id="i6" required/>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Comment: @noob незачто, если ответ вас устроил, просьба отмечать галочкой (возле голосов за ответ), ну и инфу по ссилке почитайте, не будет лишним

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю есть ли решение "аккуратнее". Но я делал это так.

```
if(element.hasAttribute('required')){
   // todo
}
```

Вариант Rostyslav Kuzmovych полноценно и аккуратно решает поставленную Вами задачу.